# How to use rxandroid to listen gps location update

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I started learning reactive programming these days. In my application, I have turned to use rxandroid for many cases that process data asynchronously. But I don't know how to apply to location listener. Is there any way to subscribe the user location change? Please give me an idea.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create Observables or Subject by using `LocationListener` and when getting callback in the `onLocationChanged`, just call onNext with the location object.

```
public final class LocationProvider implements onLocationChanged {
   private final PublishSubject<Location> latestLocation = PublishSubject.create();
   //...
   @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        latestLocation.onNext(location);
    }
}
```

Then you can subscribe to it in a class that needs location.

There are also some open source libraries that you could use: [Android-ReactiveLocation](https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation) and [cgeo](http://apiwave.com/java/snippet/cgeo/cgeo/878ed6668113a29eb8695cb556ff83fb75626061/main.src.cgeo.geocaching.playservices.LocationProvider.java)

Also, see [Observable-based API and unsubscribe issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22131779/observable-based-api-and-unsubscribe-issue)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

How about using this awesome library ? https://github.com/patloew/RxLocation

add this to `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.patloew.rxlocation:rxlocation:1.0.4'
```

you may use this snippet from the above mentioned library to subscribe on location changes, I believe this is the simplest way

```
// Create one instance and share it
RxLocation rxLocation = new RxLocation(context);

LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(5000);

rxLocation.location().updates(locationRequest)
        .flatMap(location -> rxLocation.geocoding().fromLocation(location).toObservable())
        .subscribe(address -> {
            /* do something */
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good topic explain how to convert LocationManager callback API to rxjava streams
https://medium.com/@mikenguyenvan/it-is-2020-i-still-write-a-topic-about-converting-android-callback-api-to-rxjava-stream-976874ebc4f0

In short, it's better to use Observable.create()

```
private fun createLocationObservable(attributes: RxLocationAttributes): Observable<Location> {
return Observable.create { emitter ->
    val listener = getLocationListener(emitter)
    val completeListener = getOnCompleteListener(emitter)
    try {
        fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener {
            if (!emitter.isDisposed && it != null) emitter.onNext(it)
        }
        val task = fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(
            getLocationRequest(attributes),
            listener,
            if (attributes.useCalledThreadToEmitValue) null else Looper.getMainLooper()
        )
        task.addOnCompleteListener(completeListener)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        emitter.tryOnError(e)
    }
    emitter.setCancellable(getCancellable(listener))
}
```

}

From the topic, you can look into the code [here](https://github.com/roscrazy/android-rx-location/blob/master/android-rx-location/src/main/java/com/mk/location/service/FusedLocationService.kt#L31)